# Android: spinner works in Activity but not Fragment

Tags: android, spinner, fragment

So I was able to make a `Spinner` work in a single `Activity`, but when I transferred the code to a Fragment it obviously didn't work.

I am getting an error in these two lines:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, suggestedItems);
```

and I know that the context `this` needs to be changed. I already tried to use `getActivity()`, but that didn't work as well.

Some insight needed! Thank you!

```
public class NominateFragment extends Fragment {

@Override  
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nominate_page, container, false);

    //SPINNER
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.category);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);    // Apply the adapter to the spinner

    //AUTOCOMPLETE
    AutoCompleteTextView nominateItem = (AutoCompleteTextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_nominate_item); // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    String[] suggestedItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.suggested_items_array); // Get the string array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, suggestedItems);     // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
    nominateItem.setAdapter(adapterItem);

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: If it's crashing, post your logcat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replce this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

---

and this line:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.category);
```

with:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.category);
```

---

and:

```
AutoCompleteTextView nominateItem = (AutoCompleteTextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_nominate_item); // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
```

with:

```
AutoCompleteTextView nominateItem = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_nominate_item); // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
```

Comment: then put the logcat output here

Comment: Works good. I actually figured out to use `view.findViewById` at pretty much the same time you did lol, but I will be accepting your answer anyways =] Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are welcome, anyway, getView() doesn't work because you still creating it, after existing this method, getView() should work