# Spinner works in Activity but not Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent, android-fragments

```
01-20 10:39:59.721: D/AndroidRuntime(2062): Shutting down VM
01-20 10:39:59.721: W/dalvikvm(2062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41632d88)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 2062
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqltest/com.example.jobtracker.ReadComments}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at com.example.jobtracker.JobqueueFragment.onCreateView(JobqueueFragment.java:72)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
01-20 10:39:59.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2062):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461392/android-spinner-works-in-activity-but-not-fragment

Comment: Please post the code of class `com.example.jobtracker.JobqueueFragment.onCreateView(JobqueueFragment.java:72)` and line no: 72.

Comment: Its not allowing me add the full code.. can i get ur mail id.. so that i can send u the full code

Comment: You can post your full code here-- http://pastie.org/ and share link on your question. @user3479916

Comment: http://pastie.org/9842620

Comment: http://pastie.org/9842626 - this is displaylist.xml

Comment: http://pastie.org/9842632 - this is fragment_jobqueue.xml

Comment: if i comment the spinner code , will not get the error...

Comment: but i need the spinner

Comment: @user3479916 Then add your `Spinner` in your `fragment_jobqueue` layout.

Comment: k.. but it is loading in list view

Comment: hey each job der will be status Ex: |Andrew(Client Name) ----------- Spinner with Status|

Comment: Ex: In ListView
Andrew 
14 qty            Downloding

Martin
15 qty            Downloaded

Steve
25 qty            Working

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);
```

by this

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) inflate.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);
```

Comment: 01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 32454
01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqltest/com.example.jobtracker.ReadComments}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)

Comment: Post your full logcat error in your question. @user3479916

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobqueue, container, false);

    // ONE CHANGE HERE
    ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 

    mainListView = (ListView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.list);

    //SECOND CHANGE HERE
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) inflate.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapters = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ctx,
            R.array.spinner_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapters.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapters);

    new JobQueue().execute();
    return inflate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

First change your `ctx` as below:

```
 ctx=JobqueueFragment.this.getActivity();
```

instead of

```
ctx = inflater.getContext();
```

**Your layout `fragment_jobqueue` does not contain your `Spinner` so you can not bind data directly in your `Spinner` in your Fragment class. That is the place where you are actually getting nullpointer errror.**

Answer (score 0):

> use this code

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) inflate.findViewById(R.id.spinner_status);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapters = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                    R.array.spinner_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapters.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

> now your problem will resolve. 
>   Any doubt ask in comment

Comment: 01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 32454 01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqltest/com.example.jobtracker.ReadComments}: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237) 01-20 10:27:22.923: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286) –